# Nessted Ng-Repeat breaking the inner loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to render a structure with nested ng-repeat.

My object structure is as follows

```
outercollection: [

          {
            ....
            ....
            innercollection: [
                    // number of objects here is variable. It can be 0 as well.
                    {},
                    {}
            ]
            ....
         },

          {
            ....
            ....
            innercollection: [
                     {},
                     {}
            ]
            ....
          }
       ]
```

Now the I need to render the inner collection and limit it to 2.

I need some thing similar to a nested for where the inner loop should execute exactly for a couple of entries.

```
forEach(collection in outerCollection) {
    foreach(entry in collection.innerCollection) {
          If(count ==2) 
                  break;
          // do something and increment the count
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use limitto filter for the inner ng-repat

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-repeat="o in outercollection">
    <div ng-repeat="innercollection in o|limitTo:2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if my inner collections having each one element ? This wont limit  right ?

Comment: No. this would show the one element in each collection.

Comment: Yeah I need just 2 entries only irrespective of the inner collections size.. for ex: If all the inner collections has only one element I need the elements of first 2 inner collections. The total of elements rendered should be 2.